# Yii widget CListView generates additional HTML element

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii widget CListView. Problem is that it generates additional html element:

```
<div id="yw0" class="list-view">
```

Is it possible don't let to generate it?

Answer (score 1):

- Set the empty string for the itemsTagName and it should not be displayed (not tested)
- The second solution: You can override the render method of the widget, see here this line https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/CBaseListView.php#L123 Simply create your class and extends him from CListView, then override this method as you need.

Comment: tried to set itemsTagName to empty, but it didn't work...
The second solution is a bit hard way to do this..

Anyway, thx.